# How to write data to an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

I know this is a simple question but I am stuck. I have a simple WinForms application that collects the server name, username, and password and then under service credentials, the account and password. I simply want to write these values to an XML text file (not a database). I guess it should create the file if it doesn't exist. Do I need to create a root element? Can someone please help me out?

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtServerName;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtDatabaseUserName;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtDatabasePassword;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtServicePassword;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtAccount;
```

All I have so far is:

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "alphaService.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(fileName);

            XmlNode databaseServer = doc.CreateElement("DatabaseServer");
            XmlNode databaseUserName = doc.CreateElement("DatabaseServerName");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the XML string [see this answer for many ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284331/939213) .

For example:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();     
XElement xml = new XElement("Info",
    new XElement("Password", password),
    new XElement("UserName", userName));
doc.Add(xml);
doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use XmlNode?

Comment: @user2471435 I don't know. I'm used to using `XElement`. I edited my answer to include some.

Comment: That was it! Pretty simple. The only thing I am not doing is I should not write the password in clear text. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an open ended question as you don't supply the database structure, I'd recommend though to access the DB through entity framework (google it) and then follow this guide:

[Export SQL Server Database Table to XML Using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453865/export-sql-server-database-table-to-xml-using-linq)

Comment: There is no database structure. I am just trying to write to a simple XML text file.